# locating all substring instances in a given file

Tags: c, string, substring

I'm currently working on a function to find all images referenced in an html file, currently I am trying to to find these substrings within the file: `".bmp"` `".gif"` `".jpg"` `".png"` and also want to find their roots eg: `/images/foo/` and then use these two substrings to make a new string: `/images/foo/bar.jpg` I know how I am going to concatenate the strings but I have no idea how I am going to locate the actual substrings, I feel quite overwhelmed right now and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: If you can assume well-formed input, you won't have to do any concatenation. Just find the substring, and search backwards until you find a `"`. Once that is found, you simply extract the string based on the indices found. Although, it is a better idea to use an HTML parser.

Comment: Use an HTML parser and walk all the `<img>` nodes, collecting the values of the `src` attribute

Comment: @Doug: That will fail if the HTML document uses different quotes (e.g. `'`) or no quotes at all or some other trickery that you didn't consider. It will also fail if strings containing `.jpg` or `.gif` appear somewhere else in the document, outside of an attribute value.

Comment: @Doug I considered this but here is an example from part of googles retrieval from my function: (//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b8_3615d64d.png) My original plan was going to be to find each substring and work back to a / the concatenate but I see now that even this won't work... And even if it did I for the life of me and having trouble wrapping my head around how I'm going to find each substring location.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Well said. Thats why it was left as a comment and not an answer :). An HTML parser is necessary here.

Comment: @NiklasB. sorry about that I just edited my last comment.

Comment: @Keith: As I said, use a HTML parser and be done with it. I still don't see how it's "not that simple" (because it really is that simple). I also don't get what that screenshot/image/whatever is supposed to mean

Comment: Yeah you're right I was just freaking out over nothing I took a break from staring at my monitor and lo and behold I'm back on track!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "right" answer to this question ought to urge you to use tools that were built for the job. Smart people write stuff like [`libxml`](http://xmlsoft.org/) for a reason. Re-inventing the wheel will only make things more difficult. With `libxml`, for example, you easily traverse an XML tree like so:

```
for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
    if (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
        printf("node type: Element, name: %s\n", cur_node->name);
}
```

The "wrong" answer is to come up with some "trick" for finding the beginning of an image string, either by looking for the beginning of the image tag (`<img`) or a quote `"` as Doug mentions in the comments.

You'll notice that I put right and wrong in quotations. I'm somewhat of a purist and would strongly suggest an XML-oriented solution because it's wholly generalizable and easily extendible (tomorrow you may say: oh I also need the anchor text). A DOM parser makes every subsequent problem a breeze to solve.

But if you're working on a proof of concept or prototype (or maybe even homework) where everything's well-formed and you don't release your code in the wild, the "wrong" approach may be sufficient.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that libxml can be used in such a simple way. Great sample code.

Comment: I'm just writing some code just to get my foot in the door and test some functions I wrote, I have no need to reinvent the wheel, and libxml is looking like it may be a solid solution.